# Javascript alert doesn't work when adding remote action on visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, javascript

In the code below, the alert doesn't work.  If the I take out the loadleads function, then the alert does work.  What's the issue?

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="false" controller="LeadSearchJS">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function saysomething() {
    alert ("said something.  Don't give up on me.");
}
function loadLeads(){   Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.LeadSearchJS.findAll}',
}                                                 
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    Oh Hai.
    <div id="leadTable">
        <p>
            <a href="#" onClick="saysomething();">Say Something.  I'm giving up on you.</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</apex:page>
```

Here is the controller:

```
global with sharing class LeadSearchJS {

@RemoteAction
global static List<Lead> findAll() {
    return [SELECT Id, Email FROM Lead];
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `loadLeads` javascript function is broken, which causes other javascript on your page to break.

```
function loadLeads() {
    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.LeadSearchJS.findAll}',
}
```

The `invokeAction` function you are calling has no closing parenthesis.  There is also no callback function.  It should be more like:

```
function loadLeads() {
    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.LeadSearchJS.findAll}', function(result, event) {
        console.log('result', result);
        console.log('event', event);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Awesome.  Quick followup question - I had read that using this method does not count against API usage limits, is that true?  I see it counting against API calls in system overview/etc.

Comment: So it looks like it does NOT count against the API call limit, after testing.  But in case some don't know, the Developer Console DOES count against the API call limit!  How very odd.